# How to write a multidimentional regression predictor using an RNN in tensorflow 0.11

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, time-series, prediction

This is a toy version of what I'm actually trying to do. I have very high dimensional input data (2e05 to 5e06 dimensions) over a large number of time-steps (150,000 steps). I understand I may need some embedding / compression of the states in the end (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428432/vector-representation-in-multidimentional-time-series-prediction-in-tensorflow)). But lets set that aside for now.

Take this toy input data with 11 dimensions for example

```
t  Pattern
0  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1 
1  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0 
2  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0 
n  ...
```

I want the RNN to learn to associate the current time-step with the next time step such that if the input (x) is t0 then the desired output (y) is t1.

The idea of using an RNN is so I can provide the network with only one time-step at a time (due to the large dimensionality of my real data). Since the number of inputs and outputs are the same, I'm not sure a basic RNN is appropriate. I looked a little at the seq2seq tutorial, but I'm not sure the encoder/decoder is needed for this application and I could not get anywhere using my toy data.

Following is all I've been able to come up with, but it does not converge at all. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Imports for loading CSV file
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile 
import csv

# Input sequence
wholeSequence = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

data = np.array(wholeSequence[:-1], dtype=int) # all but last
target = np.array(wholeSequence[1:], dtype=int) # all but first
trainingSet = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.Dataset(data=data, target=target)
trainingSetDims = trainingSet.data.shape[1]

EPOCHS = 10000
PRINT_STEP = 1000

x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, trainingSetDims])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, trainingSetDims])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=trainingSetDims)

outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(cell, [x_], dtype=tf.float32)
outputs = outputs[-1]

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([trainingSetDims, 1]))     
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([trainingSetDims]))

y = tf.matmul(outputs, W) + b

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_))
train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.005, 0.2).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    for i in range(EPOCHS):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x_:trainingSet.data, y_:trainingSet.target})
        if i % PRINT_STEP == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x_:trainingSet.data, y_:trainingSet.target})
            print('training cost:', c)

    response = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_:trainingSet.data})
    print(response)
```

Where the approach comes from [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3703).

In the end I would like to use an LSTM, and the point is to model the sequence such that an *approximation of the whole sequence could be reconstructed by initiating the network with t0, and then feeding the prediction back as the next input*.

**EDIT1**

I'm now seeing a reduction of cost since I've added the following code to rescale the histogram input data to a probability distribution before training:

```
# Convert hist to probability distribution
wholeSequence = np.array(wholeSequence, dtype=float) # Convert to NP array.
pdfSequence = wholeSequence*(1./np.sum(wholeSequence)) # Normalize to PD.

data = pdfSequence[:-1] # all but last
target = pdfSequence[1:] # all but first
```

The output still does not appear anything like the input, so I'm certainly missing something:

```
('training cost:', 0.49993864)
('training cost:', 0.0012213766)
('training cost:', 0.0010471855)
('training cost:', 0.00094231067)
('training cost:', 0.0008385859)
('training cost:', 0.00077578216)
('training cost:', 0.00071381911)
('training cost:', 0.00063783216)
('training cost:', 0.00061271922)
('training cost:', 0.00059178629)
[[ 0.02012676  0.02383044  0.02383044  0.02383044  0.02383044  0.02383044
   0.02383044  0.02383044  0.02383044  0.01642305  0.01271933]
 [ 0.02024871  0.02395239  0.02395239  0.02395239  0.02395239  0.02395239
   0.02395239  0.02395239  0.02395239  0.016545    0.01284128]
 [ 0.02013803  0.02384171  0.02384171  0.02384171  0.02384171  0.02384171
   0.02384171  0.02384171  0.02384171  0.01643431  0.0127306 ]
 [ 0.020188    0.02389169  0.02389169  0.02389169  0.02389169  0.02389169
   0.02389169  0.02389169  0.02389169  0.01648429  0.01278058]
 [ 0.02020025  0.02390394  0.02390394  0.02390394  0.02390394  0.02390394
   0.02390394  0.02390394  0.02390394  0.01649654  0.01279283]
 [ 0.02005926  0.02376294  0.02376294  0.02376294  0.02376294  0.02376294
   0.02376294  0.02376294  0.02376294  0.01635554  0.01265183]
 [ 0.02034193  0.02404562  0.02404562  0.02404562  0.02404562  0.02404562
   0.02404562  0.02404562  0.02404562  0.01663822  0.01293451]
 [ 0.02057907  0.02428275  0.02428275  0.02428275  0.02428275  0.02428275
   0.02428275  0.02428275  0.02428275  0.01687536  0.01317164]
 [ 0.02042386  0.02412754  0.02412754  0.02412754  0.02412754  0.02412754
   0.02412754  0.02412754  0.02412754  0.01672015  0.01301643]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on using tensowflow directly and ended up using [Keras](https://keras.io/). Following is code that learns the toy sequence above using a single layer LSTM with a second dense layer:

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

# Input sequence
wholeSequence = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

# Preprocess Data: (This does not work)
wholeSequence = np.array(wholeSequence, dtype=float) # Convert to NP array.
data = wholeSequence[:-1] # all but last
target = wholeSequence[1:] # all but first

# Reshape training data for Keras LSTM model
# The training data needs to be (batchIndex, timeStepIndex, dimentionIndex)
# Single batch, 9 time steps, 11 dimentions
data = data.reshape((1, 9, 11))
target = target.reshape((1, 9, 11))

# Build Model
model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(11, input_shape=(9, 11), unroll=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(11))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(data, target, nb_epoch=2000, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```